# Postgres select distinct values in OVER() function

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get set of unique ids as array.

Example:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, array_agg(a.id) OVER() as groups_ids 
FROM author a 
JOIN books as b
```

At this moment I get multiple the same `author.id` as many `books` belongs for `author`.

How to get only distinct ids?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show an example output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is without a window function:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, array(select distinct a2.id from author a2) as groups_ids 
FROM author a 
  JOIN books as b on a.id = b.author_id;
```